# How to create Jquery products slider?

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider

I am trying to create jquery slider that could slide DIV's. I need something like jCarousel or jquery Moving Boxes.

It should be simple sliding of 3 items at a time.

```
<div class="all-items">
  <div class="item"><img src="">Item text 1</div>
  <div class="item"><img src="">Item text 2</div>
  <div class="item"><img src="">Item text 3</div>
  <div class="item"><img src="">Item text 4</div>
  <div class="item"><img src="">Item text 5</div>
  <div class="item"><img src="">Item text 6</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions what should I use? Plugin or there any easier way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jCarousel then?  Sounds like you should be alright using it.  You may have to slightly alter it or change the target to $('.item') but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: You could also process the elements beforehand, something like converting div.all-items to a UL and wrapping its children in LIs, which would to the trick, or copying the DIVs and programmatically adding their content to jcarousel.